# Como abrir um form no VB.NET mesmo com o form principal minimizado

Tags: vb.net

Bom dia, boa tarde, boa noite, pessoa! Estou com a seguinte dificuldade:

Eu coloquei para um form abrir quando atingir a marca de 30 e 60 segundos. Tudo bem, isso deu certo, porém apenas quando eu estou com o form principal aberto (não minimizado), mas preciso que ele abra, mesmo com o form principal minimizado, como posso fazer isso?

**Meu codigo:**

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub btnIniciar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnIniciar.Click
        trmConometro.Start()

        If lblSegundo.Text = "02" Then
            MsgBox("Creeps saindo da base")
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub trmConometro_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles trmConometro.Tick

        lblSegundo.Text += 1
        If lblSegundo.Text = "60" Then
            lblMinuto.Text += 1
            lblSegundo.Text = "00"
        ElseIf lblMinuto.Text = "60" Then
            lblHora.Text += 1
            lblMinuto.Text = "00"
        End If

        If lblSegundo.Text = "30" Then
            Creeps_saindo_da_base.ShowDialog()
        ElseIf lblSegundo.Text = "59" Then
            Creeps_saindo_da_base.Show()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.M Then
            trmConometro.Start()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnParar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnParar.Click
        trmConometro.Stop()
        lblSegundo.Text = "00"
        lblMinuto.Text = "00"
        lblHora.Text = "00"
    End Sub
    Private Sub trmSairMSG_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles trmSairMSG.Tick

    End Sub
End Class
```

Obrigado

Comment: Olá @Lucas. Bem vindo ao **Sopt**. Aproveite para fazer o [Tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para perceber melhor como funciona o site. Quanto à sua questão, o _form_ `Creeps_saindo_da_base` é um `MdiChild` ou é um _form_ "normal"?